# Creation of Jenkins file from an already created Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-blueocean

I have created a pipeline in Jenkins using Jenkins UI which has the stages - Download from GIT>Test>Deploy>Put Test Report in Nexus.

I am wondering is it possible to generate a Jenkins File of the already created pipeline? Please guide.

Thanks

Comment: If you want to create a pipeline from a freestyle job this might help https://plugins.jenkins.io/convert-to-pipeline/. But I am not so sure if it wouldn't be easier to just create it from scratch and just copy the essential scripts over.

Comment: Thanks Smelm... but I am trying to create a Jenkins file code for the pipeline which has already been created.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm having some trouble to understand what you already have and what you need. So there is a project but it still needs a Jenkinsfile? Or do you have a pipeline and want to create a Jenkinsfile from that pipeline?